# Setting Frame in Present Modal View Controller in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5, autolayout, presentmodalviewcontroller

Setting Frame in Present Modal View Controller in iOS 7

I have issue facing frame, when I do present modal view controller.

```
    [super viewDidLoad];

  if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
    if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone )
    {
        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 7.0)
        {
            imgHeader.frame = CGRectMake(imgHeader.frame.origin.x, imgHeader.frame.origin.y, 320, 44);
            imgHeader.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"header-bg.png"];
            btnBack.frame = CGRectMake(20, 5, 38, 34);
        }
        else
        {
            imgHeader.frame = CGRectMake(imgHeader.frame.origin.x, imgHeader.frame.origin.y, 320, 64);
            imgHeader.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"header_bgiOS7.png"];
            btnBack.frame = CGRectMake(20, 25, 38, 34);
        }
        viewHeader.frame = imgHeader.frame;
    }
```

I put different images considering status bar for iOS 7 and iOS 6 and want to put bar button item(btnBack) at proper place, but the frame is not setting properly.
I am using auto layout.

Answer (score 0):

When using autoLayout, you cannot set the frame. You must modify the constraints themselves by setting the `@property` constant of the constraint itself.